# Cannot install uv4l raspicam

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspbian

I am having a problem installing the uv4l raspicam on my Raspberry Pi 2. I have done everything multiple times according to the instructions in http://www.linux-projects.org/modules/sections/index.php?op=viewarticle&artid=14 and search the web over and over but no solutions.

For me it seems that the first instruction for saving the key goes ok, although I don't know how to verify it. If I check apt-key list, I don't know what there should be..?

After I have added the line to the sources.list and I try to perform apt-get update, it says:

Failed to fetch http://www.linux-projects.org/listing/uv4l_repo/raspbian/dists/**jessie**/main/binary-armhf/Packages  404  Not Found

I tried to put both wheezy and jessie ending to the sources.list, and even updated my raspbian version in between, because I couldn't get it working but it didn't help.

Failed to fetch http://www.linux-projects.org/listing/uv4l_repo/raspbian/dists/**wheezy**/main/binary-armhf/Packages  404  Not Found

And after trying to update it was vain to even try further because the install command fails as well:

E: Unable to locate package uv4l

E: Unable to locate package uv4l-raspicam

Any ideas what I am missing??

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

The OP seems that simply has a typo problem, but IMO the people that arrives here is trying to solve the `Unable to locate package uv4l` when they run:

`sudo apt-get install uv4l`

So I'll try to give a more detailed steps on how to solve this problem.

First install the key for the repository where `uv4l` is located, to do so run:

```
wget http://www.linux-projects.org/listing/uv4l_repo/lrkey.asc && sudo apt-key add ./lrkey.asc
```

Then edit the `/etc/apt/sources.list` and add this repository at the end of the file:

```
deb http://www.linux-projects.org/listing/uv4l_repo/raspbian/ wheezy main
```

Finally update the packages list:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

And now you can correctly download the `uv4l`.

```
sudo apt-get install uv4l
```

Comment: Thanky you! I would have been so frustrated if the other response was the only response... this worked for me.

Comment: It has been a while, so where you have wheezy I needed to have buster ...

But how does one get around the issue where "apt-get update" with this config gives
"E: The repository 'http://www.linux-projects.org/listing/uv4l_repo/raspbian buster Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default." ?

Comment: @jg3  I have the same "apt-get update" error. But uv4l uv4l-raspicam uv4l-webrtc all got installed.

Answer (score 3):

And how stupid can one be...

Remember to write everything correctly raspbian **NOT** raspian...

Comment: Another learning point: you may edit your own question... but I already did :-)